# $\sum_{k=-200}^{202}2^{2k+4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

$$\sum_{k=-200}^{202}2^{2k+4}$$
I know I can try putting it in the online calculators and they would give me the answer, but I would like to keep that as my last resort. I am supposed to give an exact answer while showing each step. I have tried putting in $k$ values, for example

$s=2^{-396}$ when $k=-200$.
This pattern stays constant until you reach $k=-2$ where $s=1$. Then it's $2^2$, $2^4$, etc.

I do get the pattern, but how can I use what I know to find the exact sum.
I need help finding the answer and show each step I take.

Comment: Hint: geometric series. $2^{2k+4} = 2^{2k}2^4 = 16\times 4^k$.

Comment: @CuriousMind Do you know how to add powers together?

Comment: If the base of two numbers being multiplied is same, then you can add the powers. For example, $16\times32 = 2^4\times2^5$. Since the base of both numbers is same, i.e. $2$, we can add the powers up i.e. $2^{4 + 5} = 2^9$ i.e. $16\times32\equiv2^9$. This is essentially what Rocherz did in his comment, the only difference being instead of combining a product of multiple numbers with same bases into a single number, he took apart a single number into a product of multiple numbers with same bases.

Comment: Hint 2: $x^{-y} \equiv \left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^y$

Comment: Hint 3: $$\sum_{k = -x}^{-y} a^k \equiv \sum_{k = y}^{x} \left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)^k$$

Comment: An exact answer *as a decimal* would have hundreds of digits. In binary, it would be even longer, but much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: easier task:
$$\sum_{k=-2}^{2}2^{2k+4}=2^4\sum_{k=-2}^{2}2^{2k}=2^4\sum_{k=-2}^{2}4^{k}=2^4(4^{-2}+4^{-1}+4^0+4^1+4^2)= \\ 16\cdot \frac{4^{-2}(4^5-1)}{4-1}=341.$$
Now you can use the same method for your sum.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. $$\sum_{k = -x}^{z} a^k \equiv \sum_{k = -x}^{-1} a^k + \sum_{k = 0}^{z} a^k$$
2. $$\sum_{k = -x}^{-y} a^k \equiv \sum_{k = y}^{x} \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^k$$
3. $$\sum_{k = 0}^{z} a^k$$ is a [Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).
4. $$\sum_{k = 1}^{z} a^k \equiv \left(\sum_{k = 0}^{z} a^k\right) - 1$$

Using these hints, you can easily solve the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $S$ is the sum you seek, $4S=\sum_{k=-200}^{202}2^{2k +6}=2^{410}+S-2^{-396}$. Can you find $S$?